# What's a PHP CI Build Path

Tags: php, composer-php, php-ci

I've successfully installed [PHPCI](https://www.phptesting.org/) on my local server, setup a project, and run my first build.

Even without a phpci.yml, PHP CI seems to detect my Codeception tests (yay!)

However, the build log contains the following text

> Exception: Warning: file_get_contents(/tests/_output/report.tap.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/Sites/php-ci/phpci/PHPCI/Plugin/Codeception.php line 94
>   PLUGIN: FAILED

When I take a look at line 94, I see the following

```
$tapString = file_get_contents(
    $this->phpci->buildPath . $this->logPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'report.tap.log'
);
```

PHPCI seems to be building a path with the `$this->phpci->buildPath`.

What is this path?  Is it the PHP CI path?  The path of my repository?  A third working area that can be anywhere?

Where in PHP CI do I set this path?  Per project in the `phpci.yml`? Somewhere in the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found your question on my search for answers regarding PHPCI.

I don't know if you still need your answer, but I'll post it for anyone else who's wondering.

To answer your questions:

- **"What is this path?"** It's a uniquely generated path for each build.
- **"Is it the PHP CI path?"** No
- **"The path of my repository?"** No
- **"A third working area that can be anywhere?"** Not exactly anywhere, but yes.

**"Where in PHP CI do I set this path?"**
Well, to answer that I dug deeper into their source code and I found, that the original path is set up by the following PHP Code:

```
 $buildDirectory = $this->getId() . '_' . substr(md5(microtime(true)), 0, 5);
 $this->currentBuildPath = PHPCI_BUILD_ROOT_DIR . $buildDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

The generated path would therefore be the builds' ID and a (more or less) unique part. Important here is the defined constant `PHPCI_BUILD_ROOT_DIR` which is defined in the file `vars.php` in your installation directory:

```
// Define PHPCI_BUILD_ROOT_DIR
if (!defined('PHPCI_BUILD_ROOT_DIR')) {
    define('PHPCI_BUILD_ROOT_DIR', PHPCI_DIR . 'PHPCI/build/');
}
```

So the directory would by default be a temporary folder called
`path/to/phpci/PHPCI/build/4_31370/`

This folder will of course be deleted again, as soon as the build is finished.

I've then changed the definition of the folder to
`define('PHPCI_BUILD_ROOT_DIR', PHPCI_DIR . 'tempbuilddir/');`
which gives me the following build temporary build directory:
`path/to/phpci/tempbuilddir/6_65873/`

So this directory is completely customizable.

Nevertheless the Codeception plugin seems to have changed since your version, as the filename `report.tap.log` doesn't appear to be in the source code anymore.

I hope this answer gave you an understanding of the PHPCI build directory configuration. It certainly helped me to find this out.